# Wrapping cards in router-link in order to change to another view

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

So I have this component that contains workout cards, and I want to wrap each of these cards in a `router-link` in order to change to another view. How shall one do that? Also, here's the code:

```
<template>
      <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" :src="info.url" />
            <div class="centered">{{ info.description }}</div>
      </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
      props: ['info'],
      name: 'WorkoutCard',
};
</script>
```

and here's the array that contains urls and image descriptions:

```
let cards = [
  {url:"https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/700685922299019265/800090855645904916/gym1.jpg", description: 'Push'},
  {url:"https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/700685922299019265/800090863342321674/gym.jpg", description: 'Pull'},
  {url:"https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/700685922299019265/800090855645904916/gym1.jpg", description: 'Legs'}, 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don’t use Vue router for external routing, it only handles the routing within your app. Use vanilla js for this.

```
window.location = 'http://www.example.com';
```

or

```
location.replace('http://example.com');
```

or

```
window.open('http://example.com');
```

if the url is inside your app:

```
<router-link :to="{ path: `${info.url}` }">
  <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" :src="info.url" />
            <div class="centered">{{ info.description }}</div>
      </div>
</router-link>
```

if the view is outside of the app:
create a new method:

```
methods:{
 goToExternal(url){
  window.location = url;
 }
}

 <div class="card" @click="goToExternal(info.url)">
                <img class="card-img-top" :src="info.url" />
                <div class="centered">{{ info.description }}</div>
          </div>
```